# Auto mapping between EF and the database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, mapping

So what happen is that I made an EF model and commit into the repository with all my code and stuffs. Then my colleague tried the code with the same database and it didn't work at all. I looked into it and realize there was no mapping between the EF conceptual model and the actual database. I can go into each table and go to mapping window, click on down arrow to browse for the appropriate linking but we have a lot of tables to deal with. What I would like to know is that is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How did you create the model? If you chose model first, the designer will not be bound to the database until you create the database from the model via the Generate Database Wizard

Comment: Code-First with its convention based mapping is a great way to go with EF. It eliminates a whole lot of work especially when there is a straightforward relationship between our objects and the database.

Comment: I used generate from the database cause we have an existing database that we want to work on. I made the EF model on my machine, and then shared the code via SVN, my colleague suppose to have the same database and use my code to work on it. When she run my code, there is no mapping between the EF and her database, so I can manually link each table using the drop down arrow but we have a lot of tables, so I just want to know if there is a way to do it better. Would delete my entity and readd the tables work? Would that affect the sharing aspect anyhow?

Comment: No idea? :( Come on guys.

Comment: Would be helpful if you added more detail to your question, @NoobieCoder. What version of EF you're using, how you generated the model, which of files generated by EF are committed to the repository (or not), how you're storing and sharing the connection string. As it stands, the question does not have enough detail in order for people to give you meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the connectionstring has to be the same for both machine, so instead of using specific name, I changed it to localhost and it works now :) Thank you guys